# Is there a way to ignore class properties without using annotations

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

Following is the api call that return the Agent object

```
[Route("GetAgentById")]
    public Agent GetAgentById(int id)
    {
        //Restrict Class fields
        return new Agent(id);
    }
```

Agent class have a lot of fields (Let say 100 fields)

```
 public class Agent
  {       
    public int AgentId { get; set; }
    public string AgentName { get; set; }
    public bool IsAssigned { get; set; }
    public bool IsLoggedIn { get; set; }
    ......
    ......
    public Agent() { }
 }
```

Is there a way to ignore class properties without using annotations. I just want to return some of the fields of agent object before returning the agent object from api call. Is there any way to doing this

Comment: You should use Data transfer objects.

Comment: You should (almost) never return business/data objects directly from a web api method, as @AlexanderDerck writes, DTOs are the way to go!

Comment: If your `Agent` class has 100 fields, it might be time to decompose your data model into smaller classes from which to compose your Agent. It's too big.

Comment: @spender. This needs a lot of changes in project

Comment: I concur with the "Use a DTO" solution. Have a look at AutoMapper to translate between business objects and DTOs. http://automapper.org/

Comment: [Friends don't let friends use automapper](https://web.archive.org/web/20150208040444/http://www.uglybugger.org/software/post/friends_dont_let_friends_use_automapper). .Net/C# isn't javascript, and automapper is just duck-typing by another name. Be explicit. Write an explicit method to convert the entity into a dto. It takes a few moments, but provides clarity to your code, where automapper generates confusion and diffusion of intent.

Answer (score 1):

Return anonymous object with just required properties, like:

```
return new { agent.AgentId, agent.AgentName }
```

or use DTOs (which would be architecturally more correct, specially if you're building complex solution), in this example with [Automapper](http://cpratt.co/using-automapper-creating-mappings/):

```
return Mapper.Map<AgentDTO>(agent);
```

But if you really want to use "opt-out" approach and serialize just small subset of your object, and if you're using JSON.NET, you can mark just properties which needs to be serialized:

```
[DataContract]
public class Agent
{       
  // included in JSON
  [DataMember]
  public int AgentId { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public string AgentName { get; set; }

  // ignored
  public bool IsAssigned { get; set; }
  public bool IsLoggedIn { get; set; }  
}
```